# i want to add a color filter to the imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, porter-duff

I'd like to add a `ColorFilter` to `ImageView`.

Currently I'm using:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(resIdOfImageToFilter);
iv.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

I've checked Multiple Modes in `PotterDuff` such as `SRC_IN`, `SRC` etc., but I'm not getting any difference in any of the modes... All mode turns the whole `ImageView` in perfect Red color.

I need to blend RED color in the existing image so that image will look with a REDDISH tinge....

Comment: oops ...right way to do is PorterDuff.Mode.Lighten...

Comment: That's because there's no alpha channel (i.e. transparency) in your image. Usually `setColorFilter()` is used to tint icons, and in fact the default behaviour is to colorize all the image preserving only the alpha channel. `PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN` preserve brightness instead, so coloured parts of your image turn red, and white ones are left as they are.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The right way to do it was using `PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN`.

So the updated code will be like:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(resIdOfImageToFilter);
iv.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
```

Comment: That's because there's no alpha channel (i.e. transparency) in your image. Usually `setColorFilter()` is used to tint icons, and in fact the default behaviour is to colorize all the image preserving only the alpha channel. `PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN` preserve brightness instead, so coloured parts of your image turn red, and white ones are left as they are.

Answer (score 12):

You can use  **android:tint** ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter))) in you xml file. Example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
    android:tint="@color/your_color" />
```

Comment: Should be top answer.  Where your_color is something like this; ```<color name="your_color">#55000000</color>```

Answer (score 9):

Other solution, you could have kept `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` mode and use another alpha to have a transparent color.

I use 155 as Alpha value:

```
  final int semiTransparentGrey = Color.argb(155, 185, 185, 185);
  drawable.setColorFilter(semiTransparentGrey, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: how do you set 155 aplha?

Comment: You can set alpha directly, setting the first argb value to define the color inside a color.xml resource for example or in the code. Example: int FILTERED_GREY = Color.argb(155, 185, 185, 185);

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

in res/colors.xml:

```
<color name="highlight_color_filter">#A5FF0000</color>
```

in your Activity initialize the filter and highlight paint:

```
int highlightColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.highlight_color_filter);
PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(highlightColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Paint redHighLight = new Paint();
redHighLight.setColorFilter(targetHitFilter);
redHighLight.setAlpha(190);
```

then apply the filter to the ImageView:

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(ResIdOfImageToFilter);
iv.setColorFilter(redHighLight);
```

if that doesn't work try applying to the ImageView drawable:

```
iv.getDrawable().setColorFilter(redHighLight);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Not to be a meany or anything, but here is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable

Comment: This would not compile. redHighLight is-a Paint not a ColorFilter.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file you can user ***tint*** For example

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scrachImage_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:src="@drawable/eagle" />
```

If You want programmatically add color filter then use

```
scratchImage_2.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
```

You Can also remove this color filter using this code:

`scratchImage_2.setColorFilter(null);`