# Applying ColorFilter to ImageView with ShapedDrawable

Tags: android, drawable, android-imageview, colorfilter, shapedrawable

I have an `ImageView` with `android:src` set to a `ShapedDrawable`, namely a white circle. What I want is to colorize this `ImageView` in runtime responding to some events. `imgView.setColorFilter` seems to be solution, but after using this (tried different parameters) the image becomes invisible (I don't see it at the screen).

How to solve this? And are there better ways to have color circles?

Comment: You might find [this related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw) interesting.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find there anything related to this question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can't find the accepted answer related... Anyhow, here's another similar topic: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1309629/1029225). As suggested there, try: `imgView.setColorFilter( 0xff00ffff, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );`. If that doesn't suit your needs, a more sophisticated solution is also proposed there.

Comment: I've written, that `setColorFilter` doesn't work the way I expect: after applying it the image just disappears from the screen (leaving empty space there).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Alright, I had a quick play with this and noticed your issue of the circles disappearing. Without you describing *what* exactly you tried, I assume you haven't tried setting the color filter to the `Drawable` itself yet? (as opposed to the `ImageView`, which only seems to work with `BitmapDrawable`s).

The following statements work perfectly fine for an xml-declared `ShapeDrawable` with white as initial color:

```
ImageView redCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_red_imageview);
ImageView greenCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_green_imageview);
ImageView blueCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_blue_imageview);

// we can create the color values in different ways:
redCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
greenCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xff00ff00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
blueCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

The `ShapeDrawable` for completeness: (I set the size on the `ImageView`, see below)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

And one of the `ImageView`s as example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle_red_imageview"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_white" />
```

Visual result:

[image: Screenshot of colored circles]

Comment: calling `mutable()` on the `Drawable` will help keep state of drawables.

Comment: Wow this just saved me, you definitely want to apply the filter to the `Drawable` and not simply the `ImageView`.

Comment: do we get the exact color we choose here setColorFilter(0xff00ff00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY ) if we use white as original color. If not how can we get the exact color?

Comment: @SadeepDarshana: I'm not sure what you're asking here? `MULITPLY` is imply defined as `[Sa * Da, Sc * Dc]`, meaning that the result is composed of multiplying the source's alpha channel with the destination's, and the same for each of the colour channels (r, g and b). If you make either source equal to `1` (ignoring alpha channel for simplicity), then the result is `1 * Dc = Dc`, which is just the destination channel. Vice versa, if destination equals `1`, then it's just the source channel. The same math applies to the alpha channel.

Comment: got it thanks @MH. but is Sa in the range of [0,255] or [0,1]? i mean for this should i use (white) or RGB(1 out of 255, 1 out of 255, 1 out of 255) as the original color to work as I expected

Comment: @SadeepDarshana: That would be `[0,1]`, otherwise the multiplication operation (and many others) would make little sense. For more details on `PorterDuff.Mode` on Android, I'd suggest to have a [read here](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html) or start a new question if you hit any snags.

Comment: @MH. thanks, and I recommend MH.'s link for anyone interested

Comment: I had a PNG drawable for the `ImageView` and `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN` worked correctly for me instead of `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`

Comment: @RahulChowdhury: Sure, depending on your use case you'll want to explore different modes. `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` was just an example that fits the original question, and works because the initial colour of the circle is white. The point to take away here is how to apply a colour filter using one of the available `PorterDuff.Mode` options provided by the framework.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to change Image Color use

```
PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP instead
PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
```

in above example.

Comment: I think author asked about any filter, not just SRC_ATOP or MULTIPLY.

Comment: Right solution for image views with PNG source

Answer (score 8):

You can use attribute `android:tint` in ImageView in xml.

Example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
    android:tint="@color/your_color" />
```

> Tested on Android 4.1.2 and 6.0.1

Comment: nice answer not need run

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very very simple using this library:
https://github.com/jrvansuita/IconHandler

It will working like this:

```
Icon.on(yourImageView).color(R.color.your_color).icon(R.mipmap.your_icon).put();
```