# layer-list not working as expected, I want to understand this concept

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, layer-list

I have fair Idea about layer_list referred from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576945/android-rotate-cuts-off-corners-of-shape)

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#FEBB02" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <size
            android:width="40dp"
            android:height="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
   >
    <rotate
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

This is how it is look line in studio
      [image]

but when I am applying background of Linearlayout it gives this result
       [image]

I am expecting corner would be below the pointed as seen in studio.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try setting the `clipToPadding` and `clipChildren` attributes to false, inside the parent view of the linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Plz change size of Linearlayout to 150dp * 100dp.
[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<item>-->
        <!--<scale  android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"  android:useIntrinsicSizeAsMinimum="true">-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;<shape android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="true">&ndash;&gt;-->
                <!--&lt;!&ndash;<solid android:color="@color/red" />&ndash;&gt;-->
                <!--&lt;!&ndash;<size&ndash;&gt;-->
                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;android:width="60dp"&ndash;&gt;-->
                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;android:height="60dp" />&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;</shape>&ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--</scale>-->
    <!--</item>-->
    <item
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="15dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="#FEBB02" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <size
                android:width="150dp"
                android:height="70dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:left="40dp"
        android:right="40dp"
        android:top="15dp"
        >
        <rotate
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
                <corners android:radius="2dp" />
                <size
                    android:width="70dp"
                    android:height="70dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: @LokeshTiwari I think you should use size depend on the actual size when you use it.

Comment: Tried that also main problem is that corner tip is getting clipped and only square background represented I am expecting bottom corner tip should be out as seen in studio layout.

Comment: What's the size of Linearlayout?

Comment: Linear layout size is 150dp * 70dp

Comment: The size should be 150dp * 100dp.