# Diamond shape xml background for android view

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, shapes

Hi anyone please suggest me how to create android xml drawable like below image?

[image]

Now I am using below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but its result is triangle but I need above shape.

Comment: what you have tried for this . add your code.

Comment: The easiest way is use .png on ImageButton and display.

Comment: thanks for your suppor @all

Comment: i fixed with this tutorial http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-rotate-drawable.html

Answer (score 15):

Check this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="43dp"
    android:top="43dp"
    android:right="43dp"
    android:bottom="43dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape>
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#0fdcc9"
                android:endColor="#0fdcc9" />
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#2DACA0" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Perfect Answer. Just change `startColor` and `endColor` with `#66BF9E` value and in stroke `color` with `#318264` value.

Comment: This is the solution I used, but you don't need a <gradient>; <solid> will do.

Comment: @greeble31 The `<solid>` tag will work for single solid color, If we want to use more than one we can make use of `<gradient>`.  In this case, we can use `<solid>` instead of <gradient> both will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is my drawable file for diamond shape `ic_diamond.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="372.7dp"
android:height="367.4dp"
android:viewportWidth="372.7"
android:viewportHeight="367.4">

<path
    android:fillColor="#50AE89"
    android:strokeColor="#266D4F"
    android:strokeWidth="5"
    android:strokeMiterLimit="10"
    android:pathData="M188.706,51.8702 L318.105,181.269 L183.968,315.406 L54.5691,186.007
                   L188.706,51.8702 Z" />
</vector>
```

I include this in simple view:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_diamond"
    />
```

Here, is the result:

[image]

Comment: could you share me how you generate this vector image? I tried using android studio but still facing issue

Comment: I just create the svg and convert it into the vector. :D

Answer (score 0):

i fixed with this tutorial 
[here](http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-rotate-drawable.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="43dp"
        android:left="43dp"
        android:right="43dp"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:top="43dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape>
                <size
                    android:width="200dp"
                    android:height="200dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <stroke
                    android:width="5dp"
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
                <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                <padding
                    android:bottom="10dp"
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a drawable resource which creates a 200dp square and rotates it 45° to form a diamond shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="50dp"
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:top="50dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape>
                <size
                    android:width="200dp"
                    android:height="200dp"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#358165"/>
                <solid android:color="#69BE9E"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.