# Create a rectangle with triangle drawable android?

Tags: android, xml, drawable, shapes

I need to create a drawable shape XML as per the below image in which we have a  triangle in the middle of the upper side.

[image: The image needed to draw]

I do know how to create a rectangle and a triangle

Rectangle drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
<padding android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

Triangle drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#000000"  />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

How to use both of them to create that image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042603/android-how-to-create-triangle-and-rectangle-shape-programatically

Comment: create a .9.png drawable

Comment: please dont use such "monster like" xml files: layer-list>rotate>shape, use nine-patch drawable or custom `Shape`class to be used with a `ShapeDrawable`

Answer (score 2):

It seems a **9 patch** like this small thingy here

[image]

can really be what you are looking for:

[image]

Just give it the `.9.png` extension.
For a nice guide on 9 patches, see: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: I agree, you could do it with a xml drawable but that doesn't guarantee that is going to look good in every device

Comment: And I guess it would be a little harder to find the perfect receipt to it. And possibly also harder in rendering terms, maybe.