# How to make this shape in Android

Tags: android, android-shape

I want create shape such as this image :

[image]

But i do not want use 9 pach png image, i want create this shape in drawable folder.
How can i create this? Any help could be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `i do not want use 9 pach png image, i want create this shape in drawable folder` **where else** would you put a 9 patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) if your using >api 21, or [shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042603/android-how-to-create-triangle-and-rectangle-shape-programatically)(maybe a triangle and rectangle combined) with borders.

Comment: Thnx, but i have a question. how can i set border just top of shape ? or set border just left of shape?

Comment: I think you can´t define that, I would probably reuse my shapes, first draw shapes with solid black then draw same shapes with your color on top with padding to make it look like a border