# How to apply color filter\overlay on a layout in android?

Tags: android, layout, colors

I have a layout that contains inside it imageview and textview, this use this layout like a button. I want to make an overlay color like in Google Play buttons.

I found the I can do it by: layout.getBackground().setColorFilter(color,mode)
The problem that getBAckground returns null.

How can I do this effect?

Comment: Do you want to add a color filter to the imageview?

Comment: No, I want to add color filter to the layout

Comment: `getBAckground returns null` so, try adding a background color (transparent = #0000) in your xml file (or programmatically, 0x00000000)

Answer (score -1):

Try This

> [Applying ColorFilter to ImageView with ShapedDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable)

The following statements work perfectly fine for an xml-declared ShapeDrawable with white as initial color.

Comment: I want to add color filter to the layout not imageview