# Android icons pack - stop transparency?

Tags: android, icons, transparency

I'm using the : *Android Design - Icons 20131120\Action Bar Icons* pack.

All the icons are in png format. ( which supports semi transparency )

For example :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_important"/>
```

As you can see it is transparent :  ( you can see the arm at the back of the location icon).

[image]

**Question**

I don't want it to be transparent .

How can I make ( besides re-edit icons) it looks like 100% white icon( without transparency) ?

Comment: try `setColorFilter`, sample `iv.setColorFilter(color);`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan `((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setColorFilter(R.color.white);` makes it gray

Comment: try `getResource().getColor()`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan can you please write the full command?  getResource() is not defined

Comment: try `setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));` or `setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan still semi transparent

Comment: please see http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/07/changing-color-of-the-drawable-or-imageview-at-runtime-in-android/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable too

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11376610/4224337