# android change imagreView's background color real time

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have to gradient xml files.

First gradient file

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:endColor="#53D671"
    android:startColor="#46C0AF" />
```

second gradient file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:endColor="#5C2678"
    android:startColor="#FF4A5A" />
```

also I have gradient animation xml file

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">


<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/first_gradient"
    android:duration="6000"/>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/second_gradient"
    android:duration="6000"/>
```

I try to change gradient background in my layout like this(with two gradient files)

```
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) layout.getBackground();

    animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(6000);
    animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(6000);

    animationDrawable.start();
```

As you can see background has changing after 6 second.My question is.Is it a possible to check gradient background color in a real time ?
I have one imageView over this layout and I would to change background color with colorFilter in realTime

Is it a possible in a Android?

Answer (score 0):

I change the view background gradient color programmatically.

```
view.setBackground(getGradient(startColor, endColor))
```

getGradient function based on startColor and endColor for gradient (also you can provide more than two values for gradient).

```
public GradientDrawable getGradient(int startColor, int endColor){
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setOrientation(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT);
        gd.setColors(new int[] {startGDColor, endGDColor});
        gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
        return gd;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your attention .I have two questions . 1) with your function How I can change imageView Background color with setcolorFilter? 2) as you can see I have two gradients files and I try to change it with animation ,In my case, does your code would work correctly ? @Dmytro Ubogyi

Comment: You can call it on imageview.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getGradient(startColor, endColor)). Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10141607/5821289

Comment: maybe something wrong in your answer, because setColorFilter has two parameters ,first int(color) and second PorterDuff.Mode and in your method returning GradientDrawable @Dmytro Ubogyi