# How to draw the same png icon in different colors?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-paint

I have an image template that contains on the top of a transparent background a white only icon. How can I draw this icon with differents color (ex: blue, yellow, etc.)? For example I would like to print it in yellow at someplace and in blue at another place.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:tint="@color/tint_color" />
```

Result with red and yellow `tint` colors:

[image: result]

Also there are several [setColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setColorFilter(int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) methods in `ImageView`. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable)