# What is the best way to apply color filter on hair style with some specified hair style image pattern?

Tags: android, imageview, colorfilter

I am developing an android application for hair style salon.I am having two images. One is hairstyle (hair) and another is hair color pattern.
I am able to change the color of hair style based on specific rgb value.

My code is as below:

```
int color = Color.rgb(182,132, 84); // getting rgb value 
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(color, 1));

transform.reset();
transform.postTranslate(-width / 2.0f, -height / 2.0f);
transform.postRotate(getDegreesFromRadians(angle));
transform.postScale(scale, scale);
transform.postTranslate(position.getX(), position.getY());

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, transform, paint);
```

But what the solution i am searching that suppose i have color pattern image then its not possible to get rgb value from gradient image.

Like:

[image: Hair Image]

[image: HairStyle color pattern]

I want to apply the above pattern on hair image. 
If anyone have idea please reply.

Comment: Apply a ColorFilter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193447/i-want-to-add-a-color-filter-to-the-imageview

Comment: Thanks for reply @Der. But is it possible to apply the same pattern color on hair.

Comment: If "hair" is a separate image, like the one you put in your question, yes (I guess it's meant to be so). Then just put this image over a hairless head.

Comment: what exactly i want. I have one is "hair" image and another one is hair color pattern image. So i want put the color pattern image to the hair image.

Comment: Exactly. So use the code in the provided link. It will "recolor" your hair image without touching the other image.

Comment: @DerGolem, Thanks for reply.But Is it possible to get the rgb from the pattern image.

Comment: What do you mean? the RGB of each pixel? of course you can. But it's a nested loop, you have to scan each pixel.

Comment: Yes. I have all the values of each pixel by the histogram of image. but don't know how to apply each pixel on hair.

Comment: It's better if you have a face without hair AND hair as a separate image to apply over the face. By keeping the two separate, you can apply a ColorFilter to your hair only and change its color in a flash. If you work pixel by pixel, it will take forever to finish colouring.

Comment: Thanks a lot for valuable suggestion..

Comment: I posted my solution. It was funny and proofed my concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for fun, and curiosity, I tried to make my own implementation of your idea.
After preparing the two following xxhdpi images (480 dpi, so to make them scale well - then I put them in the `/res/drawable-xxhdpi` folder)

Of course, I had to carefully size the images to fit and overlap perfectly.

[image] and a white hair (a copy of yours, made "whitish" - desaturate + play with brightness/contrast) [image]

I made this layout, in which the hair image overlaps the head:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f000"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/head_xxh"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHair"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/hair_wht_xxh"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Random hair color"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the code I used:

```
package com.dergolem.abc_2;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Generic
extends Activity
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    Button btn = null;
    ImageView img = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.hair);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgHair);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnColor);
    }

    public void clickHandler(final View v)
    {
        colorize(rnd.nextInt(7));
    }

    private void colorize(final int num)
    {
        int clr = Color.WHITE;
        switch (num)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                clr = Color.RED;
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                clr = Color.GREEN;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                clr = Color.BLUE;
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                clr = Color.BLACK;
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                clr = Color.CYAN;
                break;
            }
            case 5:
            {
                clr = Color.YELLOW;
                break;
            }
            case 6:
            {
                clr = Color.parseColor("#ff888800");
                break;
            }
        }

        img.setColorFilter(clr, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```

And some of the results I got:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Even if this composition seems like an Andy Wharol's picture, it isn't. It's mine. :)
It seems like the result you are looking for.

**[EDIT]**

I didn't try this new idea, but (with some extra work) you can even change other colors:

- Eyes
- Skin
- Lipstick
- Eye makeup (this would require some patience)

Comment: Like it? I had a great fun in doing this exercise. Experiment with better colors - I mostly used the standard android ones, you can finde colors to match realistic hair colors... or fantasy tinting. ;)