# Drawable change color - keep transparant background

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have a drawable in my /res/drawable which looks like this:

[image: icon]

How can I modify the drawable (code) so that I got a blue clock instead.

- only change the red pixels to blue
- background must be transparant (in icon.png the background is transparant too)

Comment: you could us the tint

Comment: is the idea to have the user able to define their own custom colour? if not I would just go with multiple resources. or maybe a selection if you wanted the user to be able to pick a colour.

Comment: @Cob50nm it is to theme the app like change every drawable to another color (programmatically) with using R.color.myPrimaryColor.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040036/what-is-the-best-way-to-apply-color-filter-on-hair-style-with-some-specified-hai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ImageView#setColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29)

```
_myImgView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 255)); // blue
```

Comment: another question: if the middle of the clock is white, not transparant, how can I change the red pixels to blue and keep the white bg in the middle, the outside of the clock must be transparant, is this possible?

Comment: @Francescoverheye i have never try this, but i'm not sure this is possible by using setColorFilter only. like i said, i'm not sure.