# change color of bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to create a function that gets a bitmap and destiny color and returns the colored bitmap (without using paint). I found few ways of doing it but nothing works like I want it to.

The closest solution I was able to find is:

```
    public static Bitmap changeImageColor(Bitmap srcBmp, int dstColor) {

        int width = srcBmp.getWidth();
        int height = srcBmp.getHeight();

        float srcHSV[] = new float[3];
        float dstHSV[] = new float[3];

        Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                Color.colorToHSV(srcBmp.getPixel(col, row), srcHSV);
                Color.colorToHSV(dstColor, dstHSV);

                // If it area to be painted set only value of original image
                dstHSV[2] = srcHSV[2];  // value
                int color2=Color.HSVToColor(dstHSV);;
                dstBitmap.setPixel(col, row, Color.HSVToColor(dstHSV));
            }
        }

        return dstBitmap;
    }
```

but It doesn't work very well on transparent images as can be seen here (before and after): 
[image]

Anyone has any other solutions (again without using paint at all)?

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040036/what-is-the-best-way-to-apply-color-filter-on-hair-style-with-some-specified-hai It uses `yourImageView.setColorFilter(yourColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`.

Comment: I use bitmaps only, i need an fuction that returns a colored bitmap..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to extract alpha and re-apply it after transformation. And use ARGB_8888;

Edited your code to include alpha:

```
public Bitmap colorize(Bitmap srcBmp, int dstColor) {

        int width = srcBmp.getWidth();
        int height = srcBmp.getHeight();

        float srcHSV[] = new float[3];
        float dstHSV[] = new float[3];

        Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                int pixel = srcBmp.getPixel(col, row);
                int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
                Color.colorToHSV(pixel, srcHSV);
                Color.colorToHSV(dstColor, dstHSV);

                // If it area to be painted set only value of original image
                dstHSV[2] = srcHSV[2];  // value
                dstBitmap.setPixel(col, row, Color.HSVToColor(alpha, dstHSV));
            }
        }

        return dstBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I dont know what raster is and there is no HSL in android only HSV

Comment: Raster is a similar java object as Bitmap. Basically a map of pixels. The code above with some slight modification can be applied to Bitmaps instead of Rasters. Yes android only has HSV that is why above contains custom methods for RGBtoHSL and HSLtoRGB

Comment: but why it gets two rasters? where is the color and what is writeableraster?

Comment: I'll just fix your code to do the coloring with opacity intact.

Comment: I edited your code in my answer to include alpha stuff. A quick test shows its working. If it also works for you, please check as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank god for this answer! Works perfectly!

Comment: Actually... It works, but has odd effects when using the same drawable resource

Comment: @Mike Milla You should `mutate()` the drawable resource before changing it

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample code for change the color for a bitmap:

```
private BitmapDrawable getColoredBitmap(int color, Context context,
            int drawableId) {
        Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                drawableId);
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        for (int i = 0; i < source.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < source.getHeight(); j++) {
                int pixel = source.getPixel(i, j);

                // if (pixel == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                //
                // } else
                if (pixel == Color.WHITE) {
                    pixel = Color.argb(Color.alpha(pixel),
                            Color.red(Color.WHITE), Color.green(Color.WHITE),
                            Color.blue(Color.WHITE));
                } else {
                    pixel = Color.argb(Color.alpha(pixel), Color.red(color),
                            Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
                }
                bitmap.setPixel(i, j, pixel);
            }
        }
        return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: result is : http://puu.sh/eJqS9/7275c317e2.png, I didn't mean to change it 100% to one color, only colorize it..

Comment: it will change the transparent color to given color.

Comment: what you exactly required give the source image

Comment: I want it to be colorized, has a tint of color to it but still be able to see the block. here is the source image: http://puu.sh/eJrBr/0b807796a3.png

Comment: here which color you want to change?

Comment: place validation here :  which color wont to change remaining thing is same.

Comment: given color, function gets a color and changes the bitmap to the color, it can be any color.

Comment: Working pixel-by-pixel is **suboptimal**. A ColorMatrix would be **more efficient**.

Comment: @Der Golem how do i change the color of bitmap with only colormatrix?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw

Comment: @DerGolem but they all use creating new paint, they dont create new bitmap with the new color..

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
int alpha=srcBmp.getPixel(col, row);
dstBitmap.setPixel(col, row, Color.HSVToColor(dstHSV));
```

in which you calculate an alpha (probably incorrectly from the looks of that code) and then don't use it.  You are probably going to have to create a Color with HSVToColor, then set the alpha of that color, then use it in setPixel.  And you are probably going to have to get the alpha in a similar way because I find it hard to believe a getPixel function only returns the alpha :p

Comment: I forgot to remove the alpha, it is in fact incorrect. And I tried what you said, it didn't change the result..

Comment: Then as a debugging philosophy in general, are you able to completely ignore the source bitmap and just set the destination pixels to all be transparent?  Because if you can't, you can at least ask a much much simpler question here, and simple questions get better answers :)

Comment: i think i can, i will try, although i will prefer is someone will be able to come up with better colorize solution, this one is not the best, the color is too high and strong.