# Can you programmatically change color of image?

Tags: java, android

I have one white image and in app I need to show that image in many different colors.

Is there a way to change color of that white image programmatically so that I don't need to have separate image for every color?

For now I have this:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier("image_white", "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Did you try adding some color filters ? Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193447/i-want-to-add-a-color-filter-to-the-imageview

Comment: is the resource a drawable ?

Comment: is the image a solid color?

Comment: If the image is a solid color (every pixel the same color) it's better to use ColorDrawable

Comment: Yes, the image is a solid color.

Comment: this library worked best for me https://github.com/mathiazhagan01/DrawableColorChange

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is simple. You can programmatically change colors of any image using Color Filters.

Here is a simple example on how you can use it.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageV);
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

The color of the image will be changed to red. You can use any color of your choice, but the main magic lies in using the proper mode for `PorterDuff`. You can also give it a try using `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` if you are not satisfied with the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
Drawable myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.drawable_id);
myDrawable.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_id);
```

Sorry for my english.
I hope it's help.

Answer (score -1):

You can change color if you are using material design icons.

`android:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
 android:tint="@color/yourColor"`

[Here you can find material design icons](https://material.io/icons/).

Otherwise  you can use custom xml resource file to change background, but i think i won't fit your need.